# Error When Importing Bond Python Library Written in Boost Python C++

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python, bond

I get this error:
`undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6python15instance_holder8allocateEP7_objectmmm` 
which is basically `undefined symbol: boost::python::instance_holder::allocate::object`

How to solve that?

I am following the example for Bond in python [here](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_py.html#introduction)

It mentions all the parts needed except compiling the example.cpp

This is the my command for compilation

```
g++ \
-I/home/myuser/source/adhoc_experiments/python_bond_poc/real_boost/boost_1_82_0/boost/ \
-I/home/myuser/.conda/envs/archexperiments/include/python3.9/ \
-I/usr/local/include/bond/ \
\
-L/home/myuser/.conda/envs/archexperiments/lib \
-L/usr/local/lib/bond \
\
example_types.cpp \
example_apply.cpp \
example.cpp \
\
-fPIC \
-shared \
\
-lpython3 \
-lpython3.9 \
-lboost_system \
-lboost_python39 \
-lboost_thread \
-lbond \
-lbond_apply \
\
-Wl,-soname,example  -export-dynamic \
-o example.so
```

Comment: Try moving the boost `-l` lines after `-lbond` lines.

Comment: Your boost source seems to live under your home, but where are the corresponding libraries?

Comment: @Quimby tried that, also played around with the linked libs order a lot and still no luck

Comment: @n.m. libs at /home/myuser/.conda/envs/archexperiments/lib

Comment: @SeifElsehely Unfortunate, then I would into the boost library using `readelf -s` and confirm the missing symbol is there.

Comment: When you do `ldd example.so`, do you get a line with `/home/myuser/.conda/envs/archexperiments/lib/libboost_python39.so.1.82.0` or similar? By the way your symbol is `boost::python::instance_holder::allocate(_object*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long)`.

Comment: @n.m. looks like this is the right direction to look in, it is not finding any of the libraries in the -L paths I provide

Comment: `-L` is for the linker. It has no bearing on the run time. Are you running the program outside of the virtual environment? If so you must use `-rpath` linker flag (`-Wl,-rpath` if using g++ to link, research this).

Comment: @n.m. I looked into the and I solved the issue thanks a lot for your help

Comment: correction: the -rpath*

Comment: @SeifElsehely, can you write up how you solved this as answer so that others in the future with a similar problem can benefit from what you figured out? Thanks.